# How to open references in left or bottom panel instead of in a peak view

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I left-click on class definition holding `ctrl` (tested in Python), then there is "peak view" shown with a list of all class usages/references in the code.

I would like to have a full view of the list like in other IDEs (like Pycharm) to browse though them easily going to full view of those files back and forth without loosing the list of references each time I go to full view.

For example by sticking the references view in a bottom panel.

Is it possible?

There is an old issue exactly about that in here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/22261 but is resolved and it was closed when some beta proposal was added via separate extension and now I don't see anything related in Settings.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is "**Find All References**" as opposed to Go To References.

By default highlight and press `alt+shift+F12`, or use the right click context menu, or use `ctrl+shift+p` command palette.

This should open a panel that you can click and drag to the side bar, side menu or bottom as desired.

[image: screenshot of panel title]

Comment: thanks! That would be nice if there is also a way to preview occurrences in editor while iterating over the references list (like it work in a peak view), instead of being forced to click each one. That yeah - definitely that answers my question

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna change where CodeLens opens references when clicking on the "2 References" link above definitions the setting you wanna change is Preferred Location to "view" instead of "peak":

[image]